# Trouble understanding why Cantor's diagonal slash is necessary in a simple proof for Gödel's incompleteness theorem

Tags: algorithms

I'm currently reading Roger Penrose's book *Shadows of the Mind*, in which (at pp.72-77) he gives a simple, somewhat preliminary I guess, proof for Gödel's incompleteness theorem by using turing machines. However, I'm having trouble understanding the argument.

#### The argument

Suppose that we list all the possible computations that can be carried out on a certain input number, $n$

\begin{equation}
\label{firstList}
C_0(n), C_1(n), C_2(n), C_3(n), C_4(n), C_5(n), \ldots,
\end{equation}

In other words; we're listing all the turing machines that can operate on a certain input number, $n$.

Now, further assume that we have some computational procedure, $A$, which tries to predict whether a certain turing machine will stop when working with a certain input number. This procedure won't always be able to discern if a certain turing machine stops when it's fed with a certain input number, but it is *sound*, meaning that it never will say that it stops if it doesn't.

So, formally, $A$ takes two inputs: $q$ and $n$. $q$ represents a certain turing machine and $n$ represents the input to this turing machine. $A$ signals that a certain turing machine will not stop by stopping itself. This then has the consequence that

\begin{equation}
\text{If } A(q, n) \text{ stops, then } C_q(n) \text{ does not stop.}
\end{equation}

Now, Cantor's diagonal slash is introduced, in which one always choses a $q$ and $n$ that are the same. This means that we can write

\begin{equation}
\text{If } A(n, n) \text{ stops, then } C_n(n) \text{ does not stop.}
\end{equation}

Penrose here states (I'm citing him because I'm not entirely sure what the essential components of these steps are)

> We now notice that $A(n, n)$ depends upon just *one* number $n$, not two, so it must be one of the computations $C_0, C_1, C_2, C_3, \ldots$ (as applied to $n$), since this was supposed to be a listing of *all* the computations that can be performed on a single natural number $n$. Let us suppose that it is in fact $C_k$, so we have:
>
> \begin{equation}
>   A(n, n) = C_k(n)
>   \end{equation}
>
> Now examine the particular value n=k. [...] We have [from the equation above]:
>
> \begin{equation}
>   A(k, k) = C_k(k)
>   \end{equation}

Now, substituting $n$ with $k$ in the statement before the quotes we get

\begin{equation}
\text{If } A(k, k) \text{ stops, then } C_k(k) \text{ does not stop.}
\end{equation}

By then taking advantage of $A(k, k) = C_k(k)$ above, we get

\begin{equation}
\text{If } C_k(k) \text{ stops, then } C_k(k) \text{ does not stop.}
\end{equation}

Penrose then states that (not important for my question but just providing some context for readers not familiar with what this proof leeds to)

> From this, we must deduce that the computation $C_k(k)$ does *not* in fact stop. (For if it did then it does not, according to [the equation above]. But $A(k, k)$ cannot stop either, since by [one of the equations above], it is the same as C_k(k). Thus, our procedure $A$ is incapable of ascertaining that this particular computation $C_k(k))$ does not stop even though it does not.
>
> Moreover, if we *know* that $A$ is sound, then we *know* that $C_k(k)$ does not stop. Thus, we know something that $A$ is unable to ascertain. It follows that $A$ *cannot* encapsulate our understanding.

#### What I don't get

Now, what I don't get here is why the diagonal slash is necessary for the argument. Why can't I just choose two numbers; one for the turing machine, $x$; and one for the input number, $y$; and then proclaim that $A(x, y)$ has to correspond to a certain computation, $C_x(y)$? From that point on I should be able to say that if $C_x(y)$ stops, then $C_x(y)$ does not stop. An important part of the argument seems to be that "$A(n, n)$ depends upon just *one* number $n$, not two", but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

What you claim is that there must exist numbers $x,y$ such that $A(x,y)$ corresponds to $C_x(y)$. Why is that true? How would you choose $x,y$?

More poignantly, let $A(x,y)$ read its entire input and then stop. This can't match the behavior of $C_x(y)$ since that machine has $y$ on its input tape, while $A(x,y)$ has $x\#y$ on its input tape (where $\#$ separates inputs).

The trick is to use what you call "Cantor's diagonal slash", namely to consider a machine $B$ defined by $B(n) = A(n,n)$. This machine has some Gödel number $k$, i.e. $B(n)$ is the same as $C_k(n)$. Putting $n = k$, we get $C_k(k) = B(k) = A(k,k)$.

A more complicated trick that can be used is [Kleene's recursion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem), which can construct self-referential sentences. However, in this particular case we can avoid invoking the recursion theorem using "Cantor's diagonal slash".

Answer (score 1):

The argument as presented misses some quantifiers: the statements about $q$ and $n$ are assumed to hold for all possible values for them. Notably the equation $A(n,n)=C_k(n)$ is supposed to hold for all $n$, which is achieved by choosing $k$ such that $C_k$ describes the computation of $A$ for equal arguments (it would have been more precise to say that $C_k$ is the machine that proceeds by doubling its argument and then "calling" the machine $A$ for the doubled argument; this is certainly within the realm of computation if the operation of $A$ is so, and therefore such an index $k$ exists). That the equation holds for all $n$ is essential, since it allows specialising $n$ to $k$ later.

Now if you say "there must exist numbers $x,y$ such that $A(x,y)$ corresponds to $C_x(y)$" then you are no longer claiming this works for all $x,y$ (which indeed would not be true) nor even that there is some $x$ such that it works for all $y$ (which is still false). Now you don't *need* to have it for more than one $(x,y)$ in your argument, since it concludes a contradiction directly. But your problem is that there is no reason (other than the one given in Penrose' proof, namely taking $(x,y)=(k,k)$ for the $k$ he constructs) for which even one such pair $x,y$ should exist. If you fix some $x_0$, then certainly there is a computation that takes an argument $y$, prefixes a constant $x_0$, and then calls the computation of $A$; however there is no reason to assume that this computation should happen to be the one performed by $C_{x_0}$, and not even that there should be any $x_0$ for which this coincidence takes place. The "diagonal slash" is precisely needed to establish the existence of one appropriate pair $(x,y)$.